# Problems with overlaying the spatial map with a movement network

Tags: r, igraph, ggraph

In order to overlay a movement network on a spatial map, I'm trying to define my own custom layout for plotting geocoordinates as node positions, using the packages igraph, ggraph and ggplot2, among others. The below code used to work but not anymore. Perhaps because i updated packages but i cannot remember. I cannot figure out how to solve the error message that i'm receiving below. Any help with solving is greatly appreciated.

The relevant code to create a custom layout are below.

igraph graph 'g':

```
g<-structure(list(32, FALSE, c(1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 
14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 22, 25, 27, 28, 31, 4, 6, 7, 9, 18, 22, 6, 
7, 9, 13, 14, 18, 27, 9, 18, 7, 8, 9, 18, 22, 27, 9, 18, 10, 
17, 18, 22, 27, 18, 18, 22, 18, 22, 27, 27), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 10, 13, 13, 14, 18, 18, 22), c(0, 1, 20, 2, 3, 21, 26, 4, 
22, 27, 35, 5, 36, 6, 23, 28, 33, 37, 41, 7, 43, 8, 9, 29, 10, 
30, 11, 44, 12, 24, 31, 34, 38, 42, 45, 48, 49, 51, 13, 14, 15, 
25, 39, 46, 50, 52, 16, 17, 32, 40, 47, 53, 54, 18, 19), c(0, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 
35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 
51, 52, 53, 54), c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 13, 19, 21, 22, 
22, 24, 26, 27, 27, 28, 38, 39, 40, 40, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 53, 
54, 54, 54, 55), c(0, 20, 26, 26, 26, 33, 35, 36, 41, 43, 48, 
49, 49, 49, 51, 52, 52, 52, 52, 54, 54, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 55, 
55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55), list(c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
    list(name = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
    "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
    "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
    "30", "31", "32"), long = c(-79.260866474359, -80.0214733333333, 
    -76.7089527272727, -74.780105, -80.2763261538462, -80.46082, 
    -80.030754125, -80.121487, -82.1419016578947, -81.41021461, 
    -85.6918532152941, -81.2031545454546, -81.187526, -80.11719, 
    -80.5063443067816, -82.5245573333333, -78.8618875, -80.883413, 
    -79.7296606, -76.9488, -77.8201766666667, -76.5490625, -81.5434341458974, 
    -93.59755, -88.035675, -83.2922209874074, -84.5110066666667, 
    -79.1122080625, -80.173172, -77.3383016666667, -78.2188216666667, 
    -77.7654788888889), lat = c(25.7205797179487, 26.85296, 25.53793, 
    38.33654, 27.1842307692308, 24.948536, 26.99901625, 27.171273, 
    28.2081715526316, 24.6188354115741, 29.4212288229412, 31.0068890909091, 
    29.643964, 26.6099285714286, 28.4826687301149, 27.100245, 
    26.63643, 31.3834996666667, 32.6213106, 34.2073, 24.8982166666667, 
    24.3104225, 24.6719581623077, 27.90902, 30.0528425, 27.764016172963, 
    29.706515, 26.97782228125, 25.5103912857143, 34.55239, 26.6567083333333, 
    26.9487844444444)), list(weight = c(426, 58, 3, 253, 493, 
    9, 392, 7, 4, 42, 5, 2, 40, 1, 2, 74, 2, 106, 17, 1, 2, 114, 
    62, 9, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 12, 1, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 15, 6, 2, 
    17, 4, 1, 1, 1, 21, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2))), <environment>), class = "igraph")
```

Node positions:

```
nodes_pos<-structure(list(x = c(-79.260866474359, -80.0214733333333, -76.7089527272727, 
                     -74.780105, -80.2763261538462, -80.46082, -80.030754125, -80.121487, 
                     -82.1419016578947, -81.41021461, -85.6918532152941, -81.2031545454546, 
                     -81.187526, -80.11719, -80.5063443067816, -82.5245573333333, 
                     -78.8618875, -80.883413, -79.7296606, -76.9488, -77.8201766666667, 
                     -76.5490625, -81.5434341458974, -93.59755, -88.035675, -83.2922209874074, 
                     -84.5110066666667, -79.1122080625, -80.173172, -77.3383016666667, 
                     -78.2188216666667, -77.7654788888889), y = c(25.7205797179487, 
                                                                  26.85296, 25.53793, 38.33654, 27.1842307692308, 24.948536, 26.99901625, 
                                                                  27.171273, 28.2081715526316, 24.6188354115741, 29.4212288229412, 
                                                                  31.0068890909091, 29.643964, 26.6099285714286, 28.4826687301149, 
                                                                  27.100245, 26.63643, 31.3834996666667, 32.6213106, 34.2073, 24.8982166666667, 
                                                                  24.3104225, 24.6719581623077, 27.90902, 30.0528425, 27.764016172963, 
                                                                  29.706515, 26.97782228125, 25.5103912857143, 34.55239, 26.6567083333333, 
                                                                  26.9487844444444)), row.names = 1:32, class = "data.frame")
```

manual layout:

```
lay <- create_layout(graph = g, layout = "manual",
                               node.positions = nodes_pos)
```

Error message

> ```
>  Error in layout_fun(graph, circular = circular, ...) : 
>   unused argument (node.positions = nodes_pos)
> ```

Package versions:

- ggraph 2.0.2
- igraph 1.2.4.2
- R 3.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
g_new <- upgrade_graph(g)
lay <- create_layout(g_new, 'manual',
                     x = long, y = lat)
ggraph(lay) + 
  geom_node_point(color = "red") +
  geom_polygon(data = map_data("state"), aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),
                color="black", fill="lightblue" )
```

[image]